Generating date range based on allowed weekdays, repeat times and times of day in Google Sheets
Recently, I’ve been dealing with a lot of medical-related things. To make it more manageable, I decided to create a schedule that I could print out, follow, and update as needed.
Input Data




Time of day



Weekday






Schedule





Item Name
Morning
Noon
Evening
Night
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Times
Days


Item 01
1

1

1
1
1
1
1
1
1

1


Item 02

1


1
1
1
1
1
1
1

2


Item 03




1

1

1


3



Item 04
1


1






1
3





Item Name: This can be the name of a thing that I shoud take, an appointment, or any other task.
Time of Day: An arbitrary range of cells marked with 1s, corresponding to times like morning, noon, or night (can be expanded).
Days of the Week: A range of 7 cells indicating the intended weekdays for the task (e.g., allowed days are marked with 1s).
Repeat Times: Specifies how many times an action should be repeated.
Repeat Days: Specifies how many days the action should repeat over. (Note: Repeat Times and Repeat Days are mutually exclusive.)
Starting Date: The date when the action should begin. (This may not align perfectly with the allowed weekday range, which needs to be accounted for.)

Desired output
Each item’s name (from each row in the input) should be displayed based on the number of repeats and times-per-day as a list.



Date
Item Name
Time of day




10.12.24
Item 01
Morning


10.12.24
Item 01
Evening


10.12.24
Item 02
Noon


11.12.24
Item 02
Noon


11.12.24
Item 03
time not specified


13.12.24
Item 03
time not specified


16.12.24
Item 03
time not specified


15.12.24
Item 04
Morning


15.12.24
Item 04
Night


22.12.24
Item 04
Morning



See how Item01 repeats 2 times (as it has 1 day and repeats 2 times per day, and date stays the same).
Item02 also repeats 2 times, but it has two dates - 10th and 11th, as it is set to repeat 1 time per day for 2 days.
Where it gets interesting
Item03 and Item04 have specific weekdays marked, and their starting dates do not match with them.




Time of day



Weekday






Schedule





Item Name
Morning
Noon
Evening
Night
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Times
Days


Item 03




1

1

1


3



Item 04
1


1






1
3




In the output, Item03 starts not from 10th, but from 11th, and Item04 - from 15th. And then it keeps generating dates that match the allowed range until the repeat limit is reached.



Date
Item Name
Time of day




11.12.24
Item 03
time not specified


13.12.24
Item 03
time not specified


16.12.24
Item 03
time not specified


15.12.24
Item 04
Morning


15.12.24
Item 04
Night


22.12.24
Item 04
Morning



Earlier I managed to handle “continuous” items (those without specific weekday requirements) by generating a sequence starting from the specified date and calculating repeats based on the number of days * times-per-day.
However, I’m struggling with rows like these that have specific weekday constraints. The solution needs to:

Generate a list of dates starting from or after the required starting date.
Repeat items for the specified number of times or days (multiplied by times-per-day).
Ensure that first and subsequent dates always align with the allowed weekday range.

If i single one weekday row out
{1/""/1/""/1/""/""}

transpose it, add a helper column with numbers
{ 1 / 1;
    / 2;
  1 / 3;
    / 4;
  1 / 5;
    / 6;
    / 7; }

and extract a column like
{ 1;
  3;
  5 }

I can run
=X+MOD(Y-WEEKDAY(X;2);7)

against one of those values, where X is desired starting date and Y is a value from column before (1-3-5). You can sort of find the closest valid date (from which you could start generating a sequence).
Problem is,

I'm not sure if it's working correctly,
how to run it against all of them and limit it to one value (which is always equal to or greater than starting date)


For example, if desired starting day falls onto sunday (7), and the last valid weekday is friday (5, like in the example above - 1-3-5) it should not break and loop back to 1 and output next valid day (monday in this case)


and (most importantly) it does not work with arrayformula and I can't have any drag-down business in this sheet.

Due to amount of edits / additions, I'll delete, move or mess up something eventually, and all of the helper columns better be auto-populating.
And then, even if I find a 'closest valid day', i'm not really sure how to proceed in generating a valid range like 15.12.24-15.12.24-22.12.24.
Please, help.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

@TheMaster Figured it out, thank you.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ;tocol(;1);reduce(Σ;O7:index(P:P;match(;0/(C:C<>"")));lambda(a;c;let(Ξ;lambda(x;index(x;row(c)));ifna(vstack(if(iserr(+a);Σ;a);if(c="";Σ;
 let(z;max(1;counta(Ξ(D:G)));Λ;reduce(Σ;let(x;sequence(c*7;1;Ξ(Q:Q));filter(x;xmatch(weekday(x;2);filter(sequence(1;7);Ξ(H:N)))));lambda(f;q;vstack(f;
 chooserows({q\Ξ(C:C)};sequence(max(1;counta(Ξ(D:G)));1;1;0)))));let(Γ;tocol(map(ifna(filter(D6:G6;Ξ(D:G));"- time not specified -");lambda(Δ;wrapcols(Δ;c;Δ))));
 chooserows(hstack(Λ;Γ);sequence(c*if(index(6:6;column(c))="Days";z;1))))))))))))



Jesus, yeah, this is way-way above my paygrade - I won't even try to break it down. At first I thought it works (my result was exactly as yours), but if I change anything in the input, it starts to break down - omits dates, puts times of day instead of item names etc.

What should I change in the input to replicate the scenario of formula throwing an issue?

@rockinfreakshow Excellent. FWIW, I'm getting different dates for Item 3 (13,16 and 20/12/2024); does the answer make some assumptions about the location of date/week helpers?

@ToshchakPёs if I change anything in the input, it starts to break down - that doesn't help with troubleshooting - please provide specific examples of changes, expected outcomes and actual outcomes. BTW, when you uploaded a spreadsheet, the expected outcomes included "Progress" values in Column X. FWIW, I spent quite a time on this question: what happened to that requirement?

@Tedinoz Are you using the same data structure as in the test sheet OR a different one? If its the same one & seeing diff dates, then that ought to be checked out. If its a different one, my guess would be this one hardcoded part column(c)=16, which is looking at Schedule - Days (P) column.

@rockinfreakshow Tah, I'll check.

@Tedinoz Hello.
"BTW ... the expected outcomes included "Progress" values"
Yeah, I wasn't aware that someone already took the sheet and ran with it... I got a comment saying that I should reformat the post by providing plain-text examples and refrain from posting sheet links - which I did, removing a progress column in the process, thinking that it is not crucial and isn't related to the main issue / difficulty... I'm sorry if that made things difficult.
What I've changed
What I get

Formula updated. Do test it out and see how it fares now...

It looks like... it works? This is magic. Thank you! And not only to you, but everyone - Terdinoz, TheMaster and anybody else that might have looked at it.
